# How to change tabkey stop index programically and disable in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a keyboard friendly app in JavaFX. I need to manage the tab-key all over the scene and need to disable the tab-stop some of the nods (TextFields, Button ).

In my research, i get to know that Implement key pressed event every single node. is there any simple way to do it?

```
private void OnKeyPressed_MContainer(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB)) {

    }

}
```

Comment: If all you need want to achieve is to disallow tab stop on some nodes, look at [focusTraversable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty). Otherwise please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the 'setFocusTraversable(boolean)'. is the something called TabKeyIndex ? If so, I cloud set tabindex like 1,2,3

Comment: AFAIK the tab index is determined by the order of adding the controls to the scene (order they appear in the FXML if loaded with `FXMLLoader`). I seem to recall there being plans to allow for a public interface with more control over this in the future, but I can't find the JDK issue at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately "order of adding the controls" won't work in my case. that will collapse my design. and need to get focus **root-node-next-parent-child**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaFX event processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD) consists of two parts. First the event capturing phase where the event goes 'down' from the root to the child and then the event bubbling where it goes back 'up' to the root. In order to catch an event on all child nodes of a node you can catch it on it's way down using [event filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm). Then you don't have to add the handler on all child nodes.

This answers your question, but I personally feel like there should be a better way to do that than handling the tab event yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this reduced nearly 32 lines of my code. But there should be even more simplest way i wish.

Comment: maybe it is part of some accessibility feature since navigating with keyboard is about being accessible without mouse. Just thought of it.